# From 1-1000, choosing at random, what is the probability that number is prime or composite with a prime factor p $\leq$ 29?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An integer $k \in \{1,2, \dots, 999, 1000\}$ is selected at random. What is the probability that $k$ is a prime number or a composite number with a prime factor $p\leq29$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to count the numbers that are not in our set. These are $1$ and non-primes whose prime factors are all $\gt 29$. There is only $1$ such number, namely $31^2$. So the reuired probability is $\frac{998}{1000}$.

**Remark:** Presumably the person who designed the problem expected us to forget about $1$, and to decide that the answer is $\frac{999}{1000}$. And then he/she would have the pleasure of marking our answer as wrong.

Comment: $1$ is a non-prime whose prime factors are all $\gt29$.

Comment: Yes, the answer has been given as $998/1000$.

Comment: Right, I actually submitted this question (accidentally) after getting 998/1000. Thank you though.

Comment: So all is well! I don't like questions in which a minor oversight leads to the wrong answer, when all that counts is the answer.